# Identify Google PubSub Subscriber information

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a google pubsub topic with only 1 subscription. I have shared the connection information with a third party and they are consuming the messages from my pubsub topic/subscription as a pull subscriber. However, they are reporting that they can't see messages in the Topic/Subscription.

So is there a log/view within Google Cloud which can provide me information on who is accessing my pubsub topic/subscription?

Answer (score 0):

To see topic/subscription creation information you have two options:

- Use the [activity log](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity). Go to "Resource type", "Filter" and then
  "Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription" - you will be able to view all
  subscription activity. Likewise, select "Cloud Pub/Sub Topic" to see
  all topic activity.
- Use a [Stackdriver logging filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#getting-started) of
  `resource.type="pubsub_subscription"` to see subscription activity or
  `resource.type="pubsub_topic"` to see topic activity.

`

Comment: Does it provide IP level information of the subscriber? I want to see who is accessing my PubSub Topic

Comment: Yes, you have the `callerIp` in metadata section. BUT, as Google say, don't trust the network. If you want to know who is connecting to your subscription, create a service account per client and use the `principalEmail` in authenticationInfo section, it's more reliable.